# Unused Entity Issue "Expression result unused" XCode 4 (Clang LLVM)

Tags: c++, c, clang, xcode4

The following C/C++ code results in an Unused Entity Issue with XCode 4 (Clang LLVM).

```
void stringMethod(const char *string){
  while(*string!=0){
    *string++;
    //...
  }
}
```

Its on that line: *string++; so it seems like clang didnt realize that the pointer address is increased?
I don't get, how to adjust this code... Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to remove the dereferencing operator `*`, you don't need to dereference the pointer when you increase it.